# ASP.NET WebAPI OData Delta object fields is null in PATCH request

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api-odata

I have created `ASP.NET WebAPI` with `OData` support.

The Project class has a field named `ProjectType` with nullable integer type declaration:

```
public class Project
{
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int? ProjectType { get; set; }
}
```

My WebAPI Controller:

```
public class LocalModelsController : ODataController
{
  public IHttpActionResult Patch([FromODataUri] string key, Delta<Project> patch)
  {   
        var projectUpdated = patch.GetEntity();
        var projectType = projectUpdated.ProjectType;

        //projectType is null here
  }
}
```

When I send the PATCH http request (with `BSON` content type format) from client to WebAPI, the Project object has correct values of Id and Name, but ProjectType is always null.

But when I change the type of `ProjectType` field type from `int?` to `double?`, it works correct:

```
public double? ProjectType { get; set; }
```

Is it a limitation of ODATA or I were missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have worked it out. It is just because I was using `BSON` format to transfer objects throught HTTP request. It works well if I use `JSON` instead. Not sure what wrong with `BSON` format though.

Comment: can you show your client side ajax request code? I'm using an auto-scaffolded OData v 4 web api controller... and I'm using JSON.. but.. the Delta parameter is always null

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old post but I wanted to drop my solution here for any future readers it may help.

I'm thinking this must be a bug because it makes no sense, but my issue stemmed from JSON.stringify() putting quotes around all my fields then when I posted the data, the odata endpoint couldnt convert to a decimal for one of my properties. I changed the property type from a decimal to an int and the patch started working.

Alternatively you can use postman to send a patch request, one with the quotes and one without. This is how I found my issue.

Im shocked that odata wouldnt be able to deserialize from a string to a decimal but thats exactly what it does.

Answer (score -2):

You probably just need to cast `projectUpdated` as the correct type.

For example

```
var projectUpdated = patch.GetEntity();

Project p = projectUpdated as Project;

if (p != null)
{
       var projectType = p.ProjectType;
}
```

Comment: path.GetEntity() returns Project type already so why do you need to cast it?

Comment: Because you're storing it as var (var projectUpdate = ....). You can either store it as Project in the first place or cast it.

Comment: I don't understand. Are you saying that your code doesn't work or my suggested solution?

Comment: Your code does not work obviously. I think you need to learn more about how 'var' keyword works in C# first ^^

Comment: Sorry I noticed an error in the if loop. I should have been using `p` instead of `projectUpdated`. Updated.